# can upload newly signed app bundle to existing Google Play Store

Tags: flutter, android-keystore

I have existing Android app on google play store.

We create new app with new bundle id because we can't use old bundle id and we don't have source code. Now our testing period is over and want to replace existing app with upgrade screen with app decommission message.

We have existing app's play store account. So We wrote one page app to replace with existing app. We use same bundle id but when we upload, we got following error. Of course, I have signed with new key. So my question is that do I need a same key with the app already in play store?

> To upload an Android App Bundle you must be enrolled in Play App
> Signing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to opt in to goolge sign in to upload app bundle. You can upload an apk in place of bundle if google sign in was not opted in.

> Note: For apps created before August 2021, you can still upload an APK and manage your own keys instead of using Play App Signing and publishing with an Android App Bundle.

Check this link for more info
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en